# Activating a robber in Catan clarification

Tags: catan

Our family is new to Catan, please help settle a rule interpretation.

Does the player who activates the robber by rolling a 7 also fall victim to the "lose-half-your-resource-cards" penalty or are they immune from it because they rolled the dice?

Answer (score 26):

> a) Rolling a “7”✹ and Activating the Robber
>   If you roll a “7,” no one receives any resources.
>   Instead, every player who has more than 7 Resource Cards
>   must select half (rounded down) of his Resource Cards and
>   return them to the bank.

https://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf

There's no mention of an exemption for the player who rolled a 7.

Comment: The word 'every' is explicit.  There are games where similar mechanics don't effect other players (the 'debt' in expansions to Seven Wonders) but in this case the rules are very clear.